# Why is my UI blocked when using System.Threading.Task class this way?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, task

In my ViewModel I have this code:

```
Logs = new ObservableCollection<Log>();
Logs = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => mainModel.GetLogs()).Result;
```

wtih Log being a very simple class with a couple of public properties.

According to my understanding of Task class the mainModel function GetLogs() invoked this way should run on a separate thread and while it is fetching records from the database my UI should be responsive, however that is not what is happening, instead while records are being fetched from the data store my UI is blocked.

I was hoping someone could explain why... TIA.

EDIT: My understading of the Task class was incomplete, using ContinueWith method of the Task class will ensure the async execution as explained below in member replies...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you call `Result` right after you started the asynchronous operation. The getter of the `Result` property blocks the execution of current thread until the task is completed.

**Update:**

In order to get the result asynchronously, you need to call `ContinueWith` and specify a function that will be called when the task is completed:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => mainModel.GetLogs()).ContinueWith(t => Logs = t.Result);
```

Comment: In other words I should create the Task object first, call StartNew on the next line of code and finally call taskName.Result on the next line?

Comment: Thanks, that was it... my understanding of the Task class was obviously not complete, which is not strange concidering I started learning about it today :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use the Result property like this i think, [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx):

> The get accessor for this property ensures that the asynchronous operation is complete before returning. Once the result of the computation is available, it is stored and will be returned immediately on later calls to Result.

It makes the current thread wait if you access it while the task is running.

Comment: So how do you get the Result of the Task without blocking the UI thread?

Comment: You could either encapsulate the assignment in the Task itself (which is questionable since it defeats the point of having a `Result`) or you make it do the assignment afterwards using `ContinueWith` as Pavlo Glazkov said.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming mainModel.GetLogs is threadsafe you probably want something like this, which calls the GetLogs on a background thread, and then only sets Logs to the result when it finished gettings the logs. The TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() ensures that execution of that part is run on the UI thread, which will be required if your UI is bound to that collection.

```
Task doStuff = Task.Factory.StartNew<ICollection>(() =>
    {
        return mainModel.GetLogs();
    })
    .ContinueWith((result) =>
    {
        Logs = result;
    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```